# How do I make my git history more coherent?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have to use an 3rd party API for development. I write code upload to git, download the code onto the 3rd party interface and then execute the code from the API. This means a very large number of git commits. I have been trying to make my commit history more coherent so that when the module is ready I show all the changes made in the code along the way. Should I be amending each one of my debugging commits? I'm using visual studio if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have a large number of debugging commits, those don't make for a good history.  What can be useful is to either amend your commits with `git commit --amend`, as you suggested, or to squash them together using an interactive rebase.

The way you perform such a squash is to run `git rebase -i BASE`, where `BASE` is the commit before the ones you want to squash together.  You'll then get a list of commits like this:

```
pick 92a28ece5a commit 1
pick 5878fe6a98 commit 2
pick 402864eaa3 commit 3
pick d124692e2f commit 4
```

You change the `pick` lines to `fixup` on all the commits but the first one, save and quit your editor, and they'll all be combined into one.  If you use `squash` instead of `fixup`, Git will prompt you to merge the commit messages of the commits instead of discarding them.

There's an even easier way to do this, and that's to use `git commit --fixup COMMIT` or `git commit --squash COMMIT`, which create fixup or squash commits against the given commit (which in this case, would probably be commit 1).  You can then run `git rebase -i --autosquash BASE` and Git will automatically mark those commits as squash or fixup commits and move them into the right place.

Ideally each commit is a independent logical change where all the tests pass.  You can use fixup or squash commits to make changes to older commits in your branch and then squash them together at the end.  The final product will look like you never made a mistake in your series at all and wrote perfect code to begin with.

You'll also probably want to have decent commit messages, for which the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/SubmittingPatches#describe-changes) is helpful.  Describing your changes well is helpful for other developers as well as future you.  I've often found myself questioning why I made a certain change six months after the fact, and at that point the work I've done by writing a good commit message pays off immensely.

If you're looking for examples, Git and Linux have these kinds of practices and are generally great examples of this kind of approach.